# Using public key to verify signature in Node.JS crypto

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, node-crypto

Is there a good way to validate signatures in Node.JS (v0.4+) with public keys?

Current crypto module allows this with certificates but not with public keys. For example:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

verifier = crypto.createVerifier("sha1");
verifier.update("signed data");
verifier.verify(CERT, signature);
```

Variable `CERT` needs to be signed certificate (I guess the public key is pulled from that) but all I have is the public key and not a certificate.

Only solid way to achieve this seems to be dumping the contents of the data, public key and signature into files and execute `openssl dgst`

```
fs.writeFileSync("public.key", pubkey);
fs.writeFileSync("sig.sha1", signature);
fs.writeFileSync("data.txt", data);
exec("openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public.key -signature sig.sha1 data.txt", ...)
```

But creating (and deleting) files every time I need to verify a signature seems like a total waste.

Any good ideas how to do it better?

**UPDATE 2011-08-03**

Crypto module in Node.js v0.5 allows verifying [both with certificates and public keys](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/crypto.html#verifier.verify)  (RSA or X.509)

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure openssl is the way to go. Will it let you stream the values in or must that app use files? How often are you going to do this?

Comment: Regularily, but not very often. I can live with this solution but it just feels so wrong, especially when compared to the much more elegant crypto.verifier. I would prefer not to use files.

Comment: I want to pass a public key as the first argument but I am not sure whether it should be the b64 encoded string, the string wrapped with '----BEGIN KEY----' and '-----END KEY----' or new Buffer(the_string,'base64'). I tried all but crypto is still looking for CERTIFICATE. How to tell it I am passing a public key directly?

Comment: I used -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY---- and ----END PUBLIC KEY---- as I saw openssl spits out on extracting public key from a private key PEM, and the error messages went away.

Comment: I tried to use the Crypto module in node 0.8 to do this ... and failed.  You seem to have had more success, can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just take your public key and put it into a self-signed certificate?  Then node's crypto module will work fine for you.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

I would think that doing this would be much more efficient than forking an openssl subprocess.

Comment: Is it possible to generate a certificate with a public key? All the examples are using private not public keys.

Comment: All examples involve a pair of 2 keys, 1 private, 1 public. When you create the CSR, the CSR contains a certificate, and a certificate contains a public key.  Here's a doc that is more clear that the "genrsa" actually generates a pair of connected keys, 1 public and 1 private.  http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/keys.txt.  First paragraph:  "With OpenSSL, the private key contains the
public key information as well, so a public key doesn't need to be
generated separately."